# linux routing between two networks

Tags: linux, networking, routes

I have 2 Application servers connected directly to SAN server via Ethernet cables, the san server has dual network card with 2 ports.

```
                      APP1                              APP2
                     172.16.16.10                   192.168.10.10
                          |                                |
                          |                                |
                   172.16.16.1 --[ SAN DUAL NIC ] -- 192.168.10.1
```

ON SAN

When I set each nic with IP on the same subnet 172.16.16.x, only connection to single application server APP1 works.

However if I set the other nic on different subnet 192.168.1.x network connection to both servers works fine.

My question is how can I enable routing between APP2 and APP1??

Thank you

Comment: Off-topic for SO; belongs on [su]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you didn't supply your subnet mask, I've written route statements that only route to those specific hosts you've put in your diagram.  If you give me your subnet masks, then I can give you more general routing statements.

On APP1:
ip route add 192.168.10.10/32 via 172.16.16.1

On APP2:
ip route add 172.16.16.10/32 via 192.168.10.1

To make the routing persist across reboots, you'll have to add these static routes to configuration files, but since I don't know which distro you're using, I can't tell you the exact files to edit.